# How to divide result based on group after calculation?

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am using Apache Spark doing some calculation. The raw data is in below format

```
car_brand, color, type,     price
Toyota,    red,   sport,    100
Toyota,    red,   business, 200
Honda，    blue,  business, 100
Tesla,     red,   sport,    9999
```

The calculation is using SparkSQL like below :

```
SELECT car_brand, color, avg(price) FROM car GROUP BY car_brand,color ORDER BY avg(price)
```

The result may be like :

```
car_brand, color, avg(price)
Toyota,    red,   100
Toyota,    green, 99
Toyota,    blue,  98
Toyota,    black, 97
Tesla,     red,   9999
Tesla,     black, 9998
...
```

I want to get the top 3 color for each car brand and save them into other storage like mongo.

## Question

My question is how to send the result data set to other location like mongo db.

Because the result data set is a distributed data structure, it could be very big.

**Certainly I should not collect them to local, then use a for loop to process. I`m thinking re-partition the data set based on the car_brand. Then I can use 
dataframe.foreachPartiton to handle each partition concurrently. Each partion is having all the result for each car_brand, it would be easy to sort and process. I do not know if this is a good way. Or do you have any other suggestion?**

Comment: Look at [window functions](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html). This blog post uses examples that appears to be quite close to your quesiton.

Comment: @QuentinPradet window can help me to get the top N items for each car_brand. But not helping me to send the result to other location

Comment: But sending data to MongoDB from your Python code has nothing to do with Spark, right? What did you try, what's the issue? I think you have two questions here.

Comment: @QuentinPradet Hi, I have updated my question. Please kindly check the content in bold.

Comment: How large is your dataset? Are you also asking about getting the top 3 colors for each car brand?

Comment: @QuentinPradet The dataset could be around 100GB. Yes I want top 3 colors for each car brand. And to save them into other location .

Comment: I'm sorry that you did not get an actual answer (maybe because you're asking two questions). But if you think MongoDB is not the bottleneck, you can perform MongoDB bulk inserts from Spark executors. But since the data is only around 100GB, you could consider saving it as parquet and loading it sequentially (with bulk inserts) in MongoDB.